# help for google maps

Tags: android, google-maps, maps

am running commonsware project for map but the map display squares and not maps or streets[image]

Comment: i got one from google but how i can know if it valid or not ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Hassan Khwieh

i think you have not supply valid Google Map key
for review

**[Click here](http://code.google.com/android/add-ons/google-apis/mapkey.html)**

Comment: i am using the write mapkey and write api but it dosnt work , should i go out side of building to clearly connect to GPS ?

Comment: @Hassan Khwieh try with new API key using your debug.keystore .API key for each and every debug.keystore is different so they must be match